# I am not able to make the required GP to solve this

Tags: probability

In a match between A and B probability of winning A is 1/2 and B winning is 1/3 and probability of draw is 1/6.
Person who wins two consecutive    matches will win the game. Find probability that A wins the game

Comment: What do you mean by GP?

Answer (score 0):

A wins if he wins the first game (probability ???) or the first is a draw and he wins the second (probability ???) or there are two draws and he wins the third (probability ???) or ....  You should see a pattern if you write down the calculation for the first three.

There is an easier way.   You can just ignore the draws and ask for the probability that A wins given that there is no draw.  What is the chance A wins a decisive game?

Comment: The question is worded poorly (I'm not sure I get the distinction between "match" and "game"), but it does say that A needs to win two consecutive matches in order to be the winner. So this isn't really an exact duplicate of the cited question; maybe it can be transformed into that question?